# where can i find good reference for configuring openstack nova cell environment using devstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, devstack, openstack-juno

where can i find good reference for configuring openstack nova cell environment using devstack?

I tried with many links like

http://www.dorm.org/blog/exploring-openstack-nova-cells/
http://cynic88.blogspot.in/2014/11/devstack-installation-with-cells-in.html

openstack official documentation

but nowhere its given in detail, got few errors fixed some of them, but still issues exist.